# bi-directional maximum flow using ford-fulkerson

Tags: graph-algorithm, max-flow, ford-fulkerson

I think this is like an undirected graph version of max flow problem.

So for every edge a->b, b->a is also valid. its bi-directional. And they share the same capacity. 
Which means if I have capacity 10 between two vertex a, b , and I have a flow from a to b which costs 5, then the remaining capacity from a to b will be 5 as well as the remaining capacity from b to a.

My solution to this is to have one directed edge from b to a and another one from a to b.
The question is, if I decrease residual from a->b in residual graph, do I still increase the residual for the backward edge b->a?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. In every augmenting path that has available capacity, If you decrease residual from a->b in residual graph, you have to increase the residual for the backward edge b->a. It allows the flow might be "returned" later.